# Function returning different value than what is in function body before return statement

Tags: c++, recursion, stl, graph-algorithm

I'm writing a function that returns the path between two nodes in a minimum spanning tree created using kruskal's algorithm

```
map<string, set<string>> mst = { "A" : ["B"]
                                 "B" : ["A", "C", "D"]
                                 "C" : ["B"]
                                 "D" : ["B", "E"]
                                 "E" : ["D"] }
```

The pathfinding algorithm is as follows:

```
vector<string> findPath(map<string, set<string>> mst, string src, string dest, vector<string> path) {
    if(src == dest) {
        cout << "Function path size: " << path.size() << endl;
        return path;
    }
    set<string> possible = mst[src];
    for(vector<string>::iterator it = path.begin(); it != path.end(); it++) {
        if(possible.find(*it) != possible.end())
            possible.erase(*it);
    }
    for(set<string>::iterator it = possible.begin(); it != possible.end(); it++) {
        vector<string> a = path;
        if(find(a.begin(), a.end(), src) == a.end())
                a.push_back(src);
        vector<string> p = findPath(mst, *it, dest, a);
        if(p[0] != "randValue") {
            return path;
        }
    }
    vector<string> p = path;
    p[0] = "randValue";
    return p;
}
```

If I call the function:

```
vector<string> path;
path = findPath(mst, "A", "C", path);
cout << "Main path size: " << path.size() << endl;
```

The output is:

```
Function path size: 2
Main path size: 0
```

Why is the function not returning the filled in path?

Comment: Because you haven't figured it out using your debugger. This is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your programs one line at a time, inspect all variables and their values as they change, and analyze your programs' logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find the bug in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. This is what a debugger is for: to analyze your program's logic.

Comment: `cout << "Function path size: " << path.size() << endl;` you added a print out in *one* of the return paths from your code.  Add it to all of them.  And, as Sam says, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Well I couldn't figure it out with the debugger so I traced it out by hand on some paper and I found out the answer within 5 minutes. I'm definitely taking the lesson on using the debugger to heart..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my function, the solution was just swapping one variable:

```
vector<string> findPath(map<string, set<string>> mst, string src, string dest, vector<string> path) {
    if(src == dest) {
        cout << "Function path size: " << path.size() << endl;
        return path;
    }
    set<string> possible = mst[src];
    for(vector<string>::iterator it = path.begin(); it != path.end(); it++) {
        if(possible.find(*it) != possible.end())
            possible.erase(*it);
    }
    for(set<string>::iterator it = possible.begin(); it != possible.end(); it++) {
        vector<string> a = path;
        if(find(a.begin(), a.end(), src) == a.end())
                a.push_back(src);
        vector<string> p = findPath(mst, *it, dest, a);
        if(p[0] != "randValue") {
            /**
             * RETURN p INSTEAD OF path
             */
            return p;
        }
    }
    vector<string> p = path;
    p[0] = "randValue";
    return p;
}
```